# File don't get attached when I use absolute path in HTML CSS

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I was using PHP `include` function to include the header and footer but now I want to change location of my files so I created a folder named admin panel and created a PHP file in it. Now I want to connect my `header.php` file using `include` but all the path in header file are give in reference so I want to change it to absolute path but when I change it then it doesn't work.

The reference file path is given like this:

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
```

Now when I change it to absolute then it dont work

```
<link href="/home/username/public_html/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
```

I am having GoDaddy hosting so this is the way to add absolute path in GoDaddy they say. This is GoDaddy's answer link:
https://in.godaddy.com/help/what-is-my-absolute-path-16023

If I am doing something wrong then please tell me thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have the site hosted in `root` folder of your hosting?

Comment: i have files hosted in public_html folder if this is root folder then yes..

Comment: https://in.godaddy.com/help/what-is-my-websites-root-directory-16187

Comment: Try this in your **PHP** file, `$root = realpath($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]); echo $root;` what do you get?

Comment: /home/username/public_html

Comment: Then your code should work, Please check if the file/folder has the appropriate read access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a forward slash at the beginning of your path, the path will start in your root folder.

Like this:

```
<link href="/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
```

This path should work in any file in any directory.

Comment: thanks man it was just a simple mistake, your answer solved it i was using complete path /home/username/public_html this was wrong i should directly use /css/bootstrap.css thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

Best way for you is to get the absolute path through php, so you have no doubt. And to get that just use this

```
<?php
$path = getcwd();
echo "The absolute Path is ".$path;
?>
```

Suppose you site is www.example.com and you are giving the absolute path like /home/username/public_html/css/bootstrap.css it will search at http://www.example.com/home/username/public_html/css/bootstrap.css but if you give like /css/bootstrap.css it will search at http://www.example.com/css/bootstrap.css. if there is a forward slash at the beginning.

Comment: The absolute Path is /home/username/public_html

Comment: it is same what i was using. /home/username/public_html/css/bootstrap.css